# ionic 3 charts.js handle to the canvas

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ng2-charts

i have a chart like below

```
   <canvas
        height="100"
        width="100"
        baseChart
        [chartType]="'bar'"
        [datasets]="chartData"
        [colors]="colors"
        [labels]="chartLabels"
        [options]="chartOptions"
        [legend]="true"
        (chartClick)="onChartClick($event)">
    </canvas>
```

and has handle to it like

```
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective)
  public chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

This all works fine. except now i need to add a new chart on the same html page but i do not know how to create another handle to the another chart canvas. BaseChartDirective seems to be generic. how is it connecting to the canvas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ViewChildren` like this:

```
@ViewChildren(BaseChartDirective) charts: QueryList<BaseChartDirective>;
```

and then access the first and second chart like this:

```
public myMethod(): void {

  // First canvas
  const firstCanvas = this.charts.toArray()[0];

  // Second canvas
  const secondCanvas = this.charts.toArray()[1];

}
```

---

Please notice that

```
@ViewChildren(BaseChartDirective) charts: QueryList<BaseChartDirective>;
```

is exactly the same as

```
@ViewChildren(BaseChartDirective)
public charts: QueryList<BaseChartDirective>;
```